# overwriting setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I thought in the past that if I create a variable that I can overwrite them simple.
I'am trying to do the following:

```
var zoom = {
    $el : $('#Overlay'),
    nextTimer : null,
    activeDetail : -1,
    zo: null,
    init: function() {
       zoom.nextTimer = setInterval(zoom.nextLoop, 5000);
    },
    nextLoop: function() {
       console.log("zoom.nextLoop");        
    }          
}

    $(document).on('click', function(e){
        console.log("klick");
        zoom.init();
    });
```

and expected that the zoom.nextTimer will be overwritten. But it seems to be wrong, a new timer is added.
How can I overwrite it?

Please see also http://jsfiddle.net/9FXu6/

Comment: *"and expected that the zoom.nextTimer will be overwritten"*: That's indeed happening, but the value is just an *ID* for the timer. The previous timer will continue to run in the background. Have a look at the MDN documentation for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> intervalID is a unique interval ID you can pass to clearInterval().

— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

The return value of `setInterval` is just a number that identifies the interval.  You need to call `clearInterval` and pass it as the argument if you want to stop the interval from running the function again.

```
var nextTimer = setInterval(func, time);
clearInterval(nextTimer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `clearInterval(<reference to the timer>)` to make sure it won't get executed again.

You might also have more luck with `setTimout` which only gets called once.